# Laravel Dusk Test can't trigger Vue 13 keyCode in a text field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, keyboard-events, laravel-dusk

Struggling with this for a couple of days.

I need to create a laravel dusk test that uses Vuejs framework. There is a method that triggers when the user press the ENTER key. I just found out that the jQuery can trigger Enter Key programmatically by using `.trigger()` method:

> $('.text-input').trigger($.Event("keypress", {keyCode: 13}))

It works fine but it doesn't trigger the vue method binded with the `.text-input`. Any idea why it doesn't work and is there any other approach to meet the requirements?

Any help from you guys is really appreciated.

Comment: First, you are using the .trigger() method in the wrong way. And as a second, you do not have to use whole jQuery just because of the .trigger() method. Use native .dispatch() method instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess $.Event is jQuery Event wrapper around native event and it seems to trigger actual event we need native event in some cases.

```
var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
e.keyCode = 13;
e.initEvent('keypress', false, true);
$('.text-input').get(0).dispatchEvent(e);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
    <input type='text' @keypress="test" id='ok' value='2 sec wait for it' />
  </div>
  <script>
  
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { message : 'testing man' },
  methods: {
    test(e) {
      console.log('wait for it enter triggered : ' + e.keyCode)
    }
  }
});

setTimeout( () => {
  // modern browsers, IE9+
  var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  e.keyCode = 13;
  e.initEvent('keypress', false, true);
  $('#ok').get(0).dispatchEvent(e);
  
},2000)
  </script>
</body>
 </html>
```

can you try this and let us know if works or not.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to @HardikSatasiya for providing the answer. Yes it is very useful so I want to return the favor so that the future developer will make it as reference if they have encounter this problem. Apology if this comment is so much late. I almost forgot about this.

The sample above is working very well, however, I came up to another problem. The scenario is that, in laravel dusk test I want to put a text in the field then trigger the ENTER key event of Vue.js. It is collaboration of JQuery and Vue.js actually. My final code is in below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div>
            <label>Label</label>
            <input type='text' @keyup.13="myMethod" v-model='my_vue_element'/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {my_vue_element: ''},
            methods: {
                myMethod() {
                    alert(this.my_vue_element)
                }
            }
        })

        $(() => {
            // init enter event
            var enter_key = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
            enter_key.keyCode = 13
            enter_key.initEvent("keyup", false, true)

            // select element in jquery format
            let jquery_element = $('label:contains("Label")').parent().find('input')

            // this is not native in jquery I guess
            let javascript_element = jquery_element.get(0)

            // put a value in text field
            jquery_element.val('Kanpai!')

            // the issue here is that, you need to dispatch an event at the specified eventTarget, the input.
            // usefull content in this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent
            javascript_element.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"))

            setTimeout(() => {
                // trigger ENTER event
                javascript_element.dispatchEvent(enter_key)
            }, 1000)
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```